# How can I grep for Twitter-like names in sentences?

Tags: linux, grep

```
Halo '@widi' '@diah' how are you?
What the perfect rain '@James' '@diah'..
```

I have two sentences, and want to only grep words following the <kbd>@</kbd> symbol but still in the same row. How can I do this in Linux?

Comment: So is your expected output as follows? `widi`, `James`.

Comment: the output should be :
- widi, diah

Comment: This question doesn't below on S/O, it's better suited to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

If your grep supports `-P` then you could use this,

```
grep -oP '@\K\w+' file
```

Remove `@` in the above pattern if you `@` also in the final result.

```
grep -oP '@\w+' file
```

Try the below command to remove the duplicate names,

```
grep -oP '@\K\w+' file | sort -u
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if I use grep -oP '@\K\w+', the result should be :
widi
diah
james

whereas I want the result is widi diah james

thank you

Comment: @TonnyChriswanto pass the output to `sort -u` command. See the update.

Comment: still same result, it create newline each word

Comment: did you want all the words in a single line?

Comment: each word still in same line :
ex :- widi diah
    - James diah

Comment: please update your expected output in the question, because i can't format your comment.

Comment: the output should be : - widi, diah

Comment: try this sed command, `sed "s/.*@\([^']*\).*@\([^']*\).*/\1 \2/g" file`

Comment: can we delete the rest of word except word with @ ?

Comment: yep. The above sed command will do the same job. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I did, but some word still there

Comment: please updated your question with exact input and expected output.

Comment: input : please come to my home '@wid' '@diah' '@james' I need your help 
expected output : widi,diah,james

Answer (score 0):

### Scan for Patterns with Ruby

Given your example of:

> Halo '@widi' '@diah' how are you?
>   What the perfect rain '@James' '@diah'..

you can use Ruby's [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-scan) method as a one-liner in the same way you would use grep or perl. For example:

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan /@\w+/' /tmp/corpus 
@widi
@diah
@James
@diah
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers don't seem to be doing the trick for you, maybe consider `awk` like this:

```
awk -F\' '/@/{x="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(substr($i,1,1)=="@"){if(length(x))x=x ",";x=x substr($i,2)}};print x}' file
```

**Output**

```
widi,diah
James,diah
```